# What is the access code for the Illuminati safe?

Tags: wasteland-2

What is the access code for the Illuminati safe in the Canyon of Titan (marked with an owl, contains the Eye of Providence)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the password is RABBONI an it seems to be connected to the jewish word for rabbi or "teacher". How did the devs expect us to figure this one out is beyond me!

Comment: Are you sure, the accepted answer seems to indicate otherwise?

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, it seems to be **either bugged, or not intended to be solved.** At least at the time of this writing.

If you use some tools and look at the source code, the acceptable code is empty. And since the system wont accept empty input, you will never get it to open unless you use force.

Safe requires to open high level of Safecracking (7, 8). Alternatively use dynamite.

It might be a weak pun on the whole Illuminati thing, to have a safe with a infinitely cryptic passkey.

Enjoy [this list of other people trying to figure out the safe combination as well.](https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=8089&sid=51428c33acc86f938a214b4821b8bf5e&start=20)

## UPDATE

Seems that future versions have this bug fixed, where the password is Rabboni.